# How to stop Bootstrap button from defaulting to grey background?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

### What is happening

[image]

### What I want to happen

For some reason, when I click on `button-bullet` the `background-color` reverts back to Bootstrap's default grey, even though I set the `background-color` to `#FCC1C5` using jQuery.

As you can see in my jQuery code below, I have tried adding the event `click` and `focus` to stop the `background-color` from turning into grey. But that hasn't helped.

If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong that would be great!

### My Code

*HTML*

```
<div class="worksheet-problems">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group input-group-lg worksheet-problem">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-bullet"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-one-fine-dot" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" name="Worksheet-Problem" class="form-control" placeholder="Problem..." aria-label="Write worksheet problem here">
                                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default button-add" aria-label="Add"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

*CSS*

```
/*get rid of Boostrap default grey for buttons*/
.btn.button-add, .btn.button-bullet{
  background-color: transparent;
}

.btn.red-background{
  background-color: #FCC1C5;
}
```

*jQuery*

```
$(".worksheet-problems").on("mouseenter mouseleave focus click", ".button-bullet", function(){
    if ($(".worksheet-problems").children().length > 1) {
        $(this).toggleClass("red-background");
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/f27ejwjc/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `:active` for the button to also be transparent.

```
.btn.button-add, 
.btn.button-bullet, 
.btn.button-add:active, 
.btn.button-bullet:active
.btn.button-add:focus, 
.btn.button-bullet:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
```

Edit: Might also want to include `:focus` as well.

Comment: probably a focus selector needed also

Comment: Definitely, updating the answer.

Comment: and also add 'box-shadow: none;' and '-webkit-box-shadow: none;'